# Website PHP URL Content Management

Tags: php, url

On my website, I`m managing the content dynamically by manipulating the URL.
Example: **www.mywebsite.com/?site=loin.php**

But if I want to add several GET Parameters like **www.mywebsite.com/?site=login.php?username=x&password=x**, it doesn`t work. Using post only is not a solution for my project.

I Hope you can help me!

Comment: this is hackaliscious, don't use this in production!

Answer (score 1):

Additional parameters can be separated using the `&` symbol:

`www.mywebsite.com/?site=login.php&username=x&password=x`

You cannot use `?` twice as per your example: `...?site=login.php?edit...`

Answer (score 0):

Get parameters are separated by using & sign and u have missed it u have used ? just try  using &

Comment: There is another problem. If i want to add a form and i use the transport method GET.
Example: <form action="#" method="GET">
doesn`t work for me. it redirects me to the index page and doesn`t add the get parameters to the current url...